# Efficiently update (growing) columns of data+formulas, w/ automatically updated rows of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have columns of data, each cell is a formula referencing data from several rows on another sheet (based on a dropdown box).

I now need to update many columns at once and simply copying the formula down into the next cell in the column, Excel tries to match the 'wrong' cells - the column is going down, the rows are going across, meaning I'd have to type in the correct cells manually every time I copy down this formula.

The rows are updated daily with pulled data/VBA and I can't touch the formatting of the columns either.

Not sure how to do this quickly. I have dates placed down each row/column, if that could be used somehow.

[image: SO19162161 question example]

Shown: 2 different sheets, example of 2 rows a single cell will reference. There are many of these rows and columns. This is the formula:

=IF($B$7=1,'xx'!L619,IF($B$7=2,'xx'!M619,IF($B$7=3,'xx'!N619,IF($B$7=4,'xx'!Q619,IF($B$7=5,'xx'!Q619,0)))))

When copying the cells down, the formula updates L619, M619... with L620, M620... when instead I'd need P619, Q619...

Comment: edited w/ additional info

Comment: ~10 columns, the rest are based on these and are otherwise automatic. each points to it's own sheet w/ 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help if you adapt it to your situation:

You can use the OFFSET or INDEX functions to set your spreadsheet up in such a way to transpose a horizontal row of data into a vertical column of data (and be able to drag the formula).

The trick is, you need a column (you can even hide it) with your increments in the cells i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...n

For example:

A1:A101 are where my increment values from 0 to 100 are. 
 my horizontal data starts at E15, and continues on with F15, G15, H15, etc.

This is my formula:

= OFFSET($E$15,0,$A1)

When I drag this down in a column, it corresponds exactly to the horizontal rows of data. The same thing can be done using INDEX.

Your situation sounds a little more complicated, but you might be able to build on this to suit your needs.

Comment: excellent, thank you-- i ended up using something like this;


=IF($B$7=1,(OFFSET('xx'!$H$8,0,'xx'!$B39)),IF($B$7=2,(OFFSET('xx'!$H$5,0,'xx'!$B39)),IF($B$7=3,(OFFSET('xx'!$H$8,0,'xx'!$B39)),IF($B$7=4,(OFFSET('xx'!$H$8,0,'AM Email v2'!$B39)),IF($B$7=5,(OFFSET('xx'!$H$8,0,'xx'!$B39)),0)))))